# Meteor.js + MongoDB :: Retrieve values from deeply nested arrays

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm having difficulty in getting this result:

```
["Chadstone", "South Yarra"]
```

When these two values are given:

```
name: 'Soda Rock'
city: 'Melbourne'
```

From this document:

```
{
    "_id" : "axHqB4NjXbWwphik3",
    "name" : "Soda Rock",
    "storeLocation" : [
        {
            "state" : "Victoria",
            "outlet" : [
                {
                    "city" : "Melbourne",
                    "name" : ["Chadstone", "South Yarra"]
                },
                {
                    "city" : "Geelong",
                    "name" : ["Myer", "Market Square"]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "state" : "New South Wales",
            "outlet" : [
                {
                    "city" : "Sydney",
                    "name" : ["Westfield", "Broadway Shopping Centre"]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

I've tried a few methods but none output the result I want.

**Method #1:**

```
Stores.find(
    {
        'name': 'Soda Rock', 
        'storeLocation.outlet.city': 'Melbourne'
    }, 
    {
        _id: 0, 
        'storeLocation.outlet.name.$': 1
    }
);
```

Results:

```
{
    "storeLocation" : [
        {
            "state" : "Victoria",
            "outlet" : [
                {
                    "city" : "Melbourne",
                    "name" : ["Chadstone", "South Yarra"]
                },
                {
                    "city" : "Geelong",
                    "name" : ["Myer", "Market Square"]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Method #2:**

```
Stores.find(
    {
        'name': 'Soda Rock', 
        'storeLocation.outlet.city': {
            'Melbourne'
        }
    }, 
    {
        _id: 0, 
        'storeLocation.outlet.name': 1
    }
);
```

Results:

```
{
    "storeLocation" : [
        {
            "outlet" : [
                {
                    "name" : ["Chadstone", "South Yarra"]
                },
                {
                    "name" : ["Myer", "Market Square"]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "outlet" : [
                {
                    "name" : ["Westfield", "Broadway Shopping Centre"]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I had also tried to use [meteorhacks:aggregate](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate) but unable to make it work since I have not found a doc that is newbie friendly.

Your solution and friendly explanation are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an aggregation here seems like overkill. Here's an example function to extract the outlet name(s):

```
var findOutletName = function(name, city) {
  var doc = Stores.findOne({name: name});
  var outletName = null;
  _.each(doc.storeLocation, function(location) {
    _.each(location.outlet, function(outlet) {
      if (outlet.city === city)
        outletName = outlet.name;
    });
  });
  return outletName;
};
```

Which you can use like this:

```
findOutletName('Soda Rock', 'Melbourne');
```

Comment: That's a pretty compact solution than my attempt to filter down the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure there's no way to do this with standard Meteor. The aggregate package might help, but I haven't used it either. I'd use method 1 to retrieve the document and then filter the doc to find the info you want using standard javascript (or something like underscore might help you out.)